# Confusion related to Parzen window

Tags: normal-distribution, nonparametric, density-function

I was going through this tutorial related to Parzen window at http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suyash/Dissertation_html/node11.html. However, I have some confusion related to Parzen window with gaussian kernel

It's given that when we use Gaussian Kernel, the estimated density function at x is given by

$$P(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(h \sqrt{2\pi})^d}\exp^{\frac{-1}{2}}((x-x_i)/h)^2$$

where h defines the standard deviation. I am not sure how this is derived. For eg lets say I have multivariate distribution then it should be something like

$$P(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(h \sqrt{2\pi})^d}\exp^{\frac{-1}{2}}((x-x_i)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-x_i))$$

I also wonder where the determinant $|\Sigma|^{d/2}$ will go.

Also in the original equation

$$P(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(h \sqrt{2\pi})^d}\exp^{\frac{-1}{2}}((x-x_i)/h)^2,$$

the $h^d$ came because of the volume but when we use the gaussian kernel there should be another $h^d$ as well.

I am confused. Any clarifications?

Comment: I got the answer research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l7.pdf‎. This will clarify. It was stupid question :(

Comment: It was not stupid;  nice notes btw.

Comment: @user34790 can you post your understanding as an answer to this question. The link you provided is dead.

Comment: @Samidh T the pdf link is not broken but if you copy paste it, it will give some extra characters at the end on browsers not sure why, make sure to delete the extra characters after .pdf extension in the url

Comment: [This is the link](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l7.pdf)